# bigquerqy sql link a common grid_id between groups

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The starting table.

```
with t1 as 
(
Select 'obrien-t j' lname_forename_long,11 grid_id_ct ,'grid.416153.4' grid_id,2 name_seq ,1 group_seq UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-t j',1,'grid.1002.3',1,1 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence',2,'grid.1008.9',1,2 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence',4,'grid.416153.4',2,2 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence',1,'grid.484852.7',3,2 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',14,'grid.1002.3',1,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',25,'grid.1008.9',2,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',3,'grid.1019.9',3,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',9,'grid.1623.6',4,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',40,'grid.237081.f',5,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',1,'grid.267362.4',6,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',2,'grid.414094.c',7,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',1,'grid.416060.5',8,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',36,'grid.416153.4',9,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',4,'grid.453219.8',10,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',3,'grid.454055.5',11,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',6,'grid.474069.8',12,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence j',13,'grid.481253.9',13,3 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence john',1,'grid.1002.3',1,4 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence john',1,'grid.1008.9',2,4 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence john',1,'grid.1623.6',3,4 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence john',1,'grid.237081.f',4,4 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terence john',2,'grid.416153.4',5,4 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terrence',2,'grid.416153.4',1,5 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terrence j',1,'grid.416153.4',1,6 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terry',1,'grid.137628.9',1,7 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terry',2,'grid.237081.f',2,7 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-terry',1,'grid.267362.4',3,7 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-timothy',1,'grid.496867.2',1,8 UNION ALL
Select 'obrien-timothy',3,'grid.6142.1',2,8 
)
select * from t1;
```

| lname_forename_long | grid_id_ct | grid_id | name_seq | group_seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obrien-t j | 1 | grid.1002.3 | 1 | 1 |
| obrien-t j | 11 | grid.416153.4 | 2 | 1 |
| obrien-terence | 2 | grid.1008.9 | 1 | 2 |
| obrien-terence | 4 | grid.416153.4 | 2 | 2 |
| obrien-terence | 1 | grid.484852.7 | 3 | 2 |
| obrien-terence j | 14 | grid.1002.3 | 1 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 25 | grid.1008.9 | 2 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 3 | grid.1019.9 | 3 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 9 | grid.1623.6 | 4 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 40 | grid.237081.f | 5 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 1 | grid.267362.4 | 6 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 2 | grid.414094.c | 7 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 1 | grid.416060.5 | 8 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 36 | grid.416153.4 | 9 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 4 | grid.453219.8 | 10 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 3 | grid.454055.5 | 11 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 6 | grid.474069.8 | 12 | 3 |
| obrien-terence j | 13 | grid.481253.9 | 13 | 3 |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.1002.3 | 1 | 4 |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.1008.9 | 2 | 4 |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.1623.6 | 3 | 4 |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.237081.f | 4 | 4 |
| obrien-terence john | 2 | grid.416153.4 | 5 | 4 |
| obrien-terrence | 2 | grid.416153.4 | 1 | 5 |
| obrien-terrence j | 1 | grid.416153.4 | 1 | 6 |
| obrien-terry | 1 | grid.137628.9 | 1 | 7 |
| obrien-terry | 2 | grid.237081.f | 2 | 7 |
| obrien-terry | 1 | grid.267362.4 | 3 | 7 |
| obrien-timothy | 1 | grid.496867.2 | 1 | 8 |
| obrien-timothy | 3 | grid.6142.1 | 2 | 8 |

END RESULT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7bf0.png)
The desire result

The colors represent links between the different group_seq. There maybe be more then I have shown.
Group_seq 7 (o'brien-terry) can be linked to 3 (o'brien-terence j) if I can link these 2 then I can link o'brien-terry to 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Ideally a boolean flag of true or false would be useful to show all the group_seq that are linked and the ones that are not.
In this example o'brien-timothy would be FALSE, all others would be TRUE.

Thanks in advance.
It has to be a BQ solution prefereably without creating functions or stored procedures.

The grid_id grid.416153.4 is common to group_se 1,2,3,4,5,6

| lname_forename_long | grid_id_ct | grid_id | name_seq | group_seq | links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obrien-t j | 1 | grid.1002.3 | 1 | 1 |  |
| obrien-t j | 11 | grid.416153.4 | 2 | 1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| obrien-terence | 2 | grid.1008.9 | 1 | 2 |  |
| obrien-terence | 4 | grid.416153.4 | 2 | 2 | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| obrien-terence | 1 | grid.484852.7 | 3 | 2 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 14 | grid.1002.3 | 1 | 3 | 3,7 |
| obrien-terence j | 25 | grid.1008.9 | 2 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 3 | grid.1019.9 | 3 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 9 | grid.1623.6 | 4 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 40 | grid.237081.f | 5 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 1 | grid.267362.4 | 6 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 2 | grid.414094.c | 7 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 1 | grid.416060.5 | 8 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 36 | grid.416153.4 | 9 | 3 | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| obrien-terence j | 4 | grid.453219.8 | 10 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 3 | grid.454055.5 | 11 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 6 | grid.474069.8 | 12 | 3 |  |
| obrien-terence j | 13 | grid.481253.9 | 13 | 3 | 3,4 |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.1002.3 | 1 | 4 |  |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.1008.9 | 2 | 4 |  |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.1623.6 | 3 | 4 |  |
| obrien-terence john | 1 | grid.237081.f | 4 | 4 | 3,4 |
| obrien-terence john | 2 | grid.416153.4 | 5 | 4 | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| obrien-terrence | 2 | grid.416153.4 | 1 | 5 | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| obrien-terrence j | 1 | grid.416153.4 | 1 | 6 | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| obrien-terry | 1 | grid.137628.9 | 1 | 7 |  |
| obrien-terry | 2 | grid.237081.f | 2 | 7 | 3,7 |
| obrien-terry | 1 | grid.267362.4 | 3 | 7 |  |
| obrien-timothy | 1 | grid.496867.2 | 1 | 8 |  |
| obrien-timothy | 3 | grid.6142.1 | 2 | 8 |  |

Comment: your "starting" table and expected result look exactly same !! so, what is the question here?

Comment: The expected results has an extra column called links, that's where it specifies the the relationship, ie common grid_id values between group_seq.

Comment: I see `links` col in your "starting" table example. so in reality it does not exists here  - right?

Comment: Sorry I messed up. I will modify. There is no links column in the starting table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, if(count(*) over win > 1, string_agg('' || group_seq) over win, '') links
from t1
window win as (partition by grid_id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant, I had tried so many different approaches, this is my first encounter to see the window function. There is a second part to the question, I did not want to over complicate it, I said I would open a follow on question if the first part was possible.

Comment: I accepted the answer yesterday., Green Check Mark